# Call asmx service from SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, asmx

I am trying to call admin `asmx` service from  SharePoint Designer but am getting an unauthorized error.

It require admin credential but I am unable to pass admin credential from SharePoint Designer.

```
servername:portname/_vti_adm/Admin.asmx
```

Please help me to pass value to asmx service from SharePoint Designer.

Comment: what header i need to pass to get access to admin asmx  because to call admin asmx service i would require farm credential to access the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2010 or 2013? either way, are you on the same domain?

- In 2013 you have a new activity - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx
- In 2010, unless you use a 3rd party product, such as Nintex/K2 you
  would either need to build your activity, or rely on the comunity
  developments, such as those on Codeplex
  (https://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Call+a+Web+Service+Action)
  or
  http://paulgalvinsoldblog.wordpress.com/2008/03/10/integrate-sharepoint-designer-workflows-with-web-services/

Comment: i am not on same domain . i will be connecting to WCF service and then invoke Admin asmx service to enable me to create site collection.